# How to add mongodb server to dotnet project installer

Tags: c#, .net, mongodb, .net-core, executable

I have created an installer for my dotnet project by running `dotnet publish -r osx-arm64`. However, when I try to run the executeable it looks like it does start the server on `http://localhost:5000`.

Here are the logs:

```
Starting C-Store SCP server on port 11112
info: Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime[14]
      Now listening on: http://localhost:5000
info: Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime[14]
      Now listening on: https://localhost:5001
info: Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime[0]
      Application started. Press Ctrl+C to shut down.
info: Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime[0]
      Hosting environment: Production
info: Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime[0]
```

However, since my GET endpoint fetches data from a local mongo server, when I try to run the GET endpoint `http://localhost:5000/api/getItems` it throws an error as shown below

```
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel[13]
  Connection id "XXXXXXX", Request id "XXXXX": An unhandled exception was thrown by the application.
  System.ArgumentNullException: Value cannot be null. (Parameter 'connectionString')
     at MongoDB.Driver.Core.Misc.Ensure.IsNotNull[T](T value, String paramName)
     at MongoDB.Driver.Core.Configuration.ConnectionString..ctor(String connectionString, Boolean isInternalRepresentation, IDnsResolver dnsResolver)
     at MongoDB.Driver.Core.Configuration.ConnectionString..ctor(String connectionString)
     at MongoDB.Driver.MongoUrlBuilder.Parse(String url)
     at MongoDB.Driver.MongoUrlBuilder..ctor(String url)
     at MongoDB.Driver.MongoUrl..ctor(String url)
     at MongoDB.Driver.MongoClientSettings.FromConnectionString(String connectionString)
     at MongoDB.Driver.MongoClient..ctor(String connectionString)
```

I am assuming this is because there's no mongodb server/driver in the executable?

I need some suggestion on how I can include the mongodb server on the executable which will automatically spin up once I run the executable. My overall goal is to have an executable for my dotnet project which contains a mongo server with it. Thanks!

Comment: it's because connection string is null

Comment: The `appsettings.json` inside my publish folder is:

```
{
  "RouterDatabase": {
    "ConnectionString": "mongodb://localhost:27017",
    "DatabaseName": "XXX",
    "ApiEndpointsCollectionName": "XXX"
  },
  "Logging": {
    "LogLevel": {
      "Default": "Information",
      "Microsoft.AspNetCore": "Warning"
    }
  },
  "AllowedHosts": "*"
}
```

Comment: idk, it looks like you did something wrong, but the error is clear and says only about missed connection string